# Daily Build and SQL Server Changes

Tags: version-control, build-process, change-management

I am about to try and automate a daily build, which will involve database changes, code generation, and of course a build, commit, and later on a deployment.  At the moment, each developer on the team includes their structure and data changes for the DB in two files respectively, e.g. 6.029_Brady_Data.sql.  Each structure and data file includes all changes for a version, but all changes are repeatable, i.e. with EXISTS checks etc, so they can be run every day if needed.

What can I do to bring more order to this process, which is currently basically concatenate all structure change files, run them repeatedly until all dependencies are resolved, then repeat with the data change files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a database project using Visual studio database edition, put it into source control and let the developers check in their code. I have done this and it works good with daily builds and offer a lot of support for structuring your database code. See this blog post for features

http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2008/01/Handling-Database-easily-with-Visual-Studio-2008.aspx